# Not able to get Softmax working in code

Tags: python-3.x, keras

Hi am working with images shape (160,320,3), I have set up below code and want to end it with a Softmax function however am getting error as follows "***ValueError: Error when checking target: expected softmax1 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)***"

Please see code as below:

```
model = Sequential()

with tf.name_scope("Lamda"):
    model.add(Lambda(lambda x: (x / 255.0) - 0.5, input_shape=(160,320,3), name='lamda1'))
with tf.name_scope("Cropping"):
    model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((70,25), (0,0)), input_shape=(160,320,3), name='crop1'))
with tf.name_scope("Drop"):
    model.add(Dropout(0.5, name='drop1'))
with tf.name_scope("conv"):
    model.add(Convolution2D(24, (5,5), activation="relu", strides=(2, 2), name='conv1'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(36, (5,5), activation="relu", strides=(2, 2), name='conv2'))  
    model.add(Convolution2D(48, (5,5), activation="relu", strides=(2, 2), name='conv3'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", name='conv4'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu", name='conv5'))
with tf.name_scope("Flat"):
    model.add(Flatten(name='flat1'))
with tf.name_scope("Dencity"):
    model.add(Dense(100, name='Dense1'))
with tf.name_scope("Drop"):
    model.add(Dropout(0.2, name='drop2'))
with tf.name_scope("Dencity"):
    model.add(Dense(75, name='Dense2'))
with tf.name_scope("Drop"):
    model.add(Dropout(0.2, name='drop3'))
with tf.name_scope("Dencity"):
    model.add(Dense(10, name='Dense3'))
with tf.name_scope("Soft"):
    model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax", name='softmax1'))

model.summary()

with tf.name_scope("Loss"):
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, callbacks=[cb], verbose=2)
```

The model summary give that output shape is 10 and have tried various modes but still getting the same issue, very much appreciate some support and guidance as am new to Keras.

---

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

lamda1 (Lambda)              (None, 160, 320, 3)       0

---

crop1 (Cropping2D)           (None, 65, 320, 3)        0

---

drop1 (Dropout)              (None, 65, 320, 3)        0

---

conv1 (Conv2D)               (None, 31, 158, 24)       1824

---

conv2 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 77, 36)        21636

---

conv3 (Conv2D)               (None, 5, 37, 48)         43248

---

conv4 (Conv2D)               (None, 3, 35, 64)         27712

---

conv5 (Conv2D)               (None, 1, 33, 64)         36928

---

flat1 (Flatten)              (None, 2112)              0

---

Dense1 (Dense)               (None, 100)               211300

---

drop2 (Dropout)              (None, 100)               0

---

Dense2 (Dense)               (None, 75)                7575

---

drop3 (Dropout)              (None, 75)                0

---

Dense3 (Dense)               (None, 10)                760

---

softmax1 (Dense)             (None, 10)                110

Comment: shape of X_train,y_train?

Comment: You could try one-hot encoding your y variable using:  keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None).

Comment: Or don't one-hot encode `y_train` and use `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` as loss function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342857/2099607) for more info.

Comment: used 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' and error removed however result for loss = loss: nan

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction:**

Convert you y_test and y_train to categorical. Softmax is supposed to tell the probability of every class that how much percent this class belongs to the image we are feeding to the neural net. So you have to convert you Y-test to a sparse array where all the classes are zero and the true label is 1.

like I have 3 classes ( 1.cat, 2.dog, 3.goat) I feed an image of dog its label in an array will be 2. But when I converted it into categorical array it becomes. [0,1,0] Now when softmax predict this image it becomes. [0.12,0.98,0.11] means its

0.12% similar to cat 
0.98% similar to dog
0.11% similar to goat

Thats how softmax give us prediction.

**Problem:**

Now You problem is that your y_test in the form of [1,2,3] but softmax required that their will be a 3 element array against every label.i.e `[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]`So that softmax will be able to give probability of every class to you. In simple softmax requiring an array against one image where all the elements are 0 except the true label. But when softmax see label its just a 1 element so your error arise that softmax is looking for 10 element array but got 1 element.

**Solution:**
Add this code of line this will convert your every image label to a 10 element array which your softmax is requiring.

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
```